# can shortening be used to replace lard in baking bread?

Tags: bread

I have a bread recipe that calls for lard. Is it possible to replace it with shortening and still get the same soft texture in the bread.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, shortening is a very standard substitution for lard. I can't swear that you're going to love the results, or that it will be *every bit* as soft, but there is no good reason not to try.